# Prove that $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}\ge 0$ and $\lVert f+g\rVert_{\infty}\le \rVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\rVert g \lVert_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a measurable function we define:

$$\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}=\inf\{\alpha\ge 0\;|\; |f(x)|\le \alpha\; \text{a.e.}\; \text{in}\;X\}$$

$(1)$ From this definition I can't see how that could be $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}\ge 0$, could someone explain to me?

$(2)$ I must prove that $$\lVert f+g\rVert_{\infty}\le \rVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\rVert g \lVert_{\infty}$$
where $f,g\colon X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are measurable functions.

**My Solution**
Results that $$|f(x)+g(x)|\le |f(x)|+|g(x)|\le \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\lVert g \rVert_{\infty}\;\text{a.e in}\; X $$

We suppose that $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\lVert g \rVert_{\infty}<\infty$, then for the above inequality we deduce that $\lVert f+g\rVert_{\infty}<\infty$ and since $$\lVert f+ g\rVert_{\infty}\in \{\alpha\ge 0\;|\; |f(x)+g(x)|\le \alpha\;\text{a.e in}\; X\}$$ we have that $$\lVert f+g \rVert_{\infty}\le \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\lVert g \rVert_{\infty}$$

If $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\lVert g \rVert_{\infty}=\infty$, can I still conclude that $\lVert f+g\rVert_{\infty}\le \rVert f \rVert_{\infty}+\rVert g \lVert_{\infty}?$

Comment: That $\|\cdot\|_\infty \geq 0$ follows from basic properties of infimum.  Also, $\infty \geq x$ for every $x\in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$

Comment: In other words, $0$ is a lower bound for the set. If that set is nonempty then the infimum (largest lower bound) must be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\{\alpha\ge0\mid\forall x,|f(x)|<\alpha\}\subset(0,\infty)$. Since $A\subset B$, then $\inf A\ge\inf B$, so $\|f\|_\infty=\inf\{\alpha\ge0\mid\forall x,|f(x)|<\alpha\}\ge\inf(0,\infty)=0$.
2. Sure. $\infty$ is bigger than every real number and $\infty\le\infty$. So if $\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty=\infty$, regardless what $\|f+g\|_\infty$ is, $\|f+g\|_\infty\le \|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty$ holds. And you already prove when $\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty<\infty$ then $\|f+g\|_\infty\le \|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty$ holds. Done!